# Unable to pull a bts.dot.gov MapLayer using Leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet, esri-leaflet, dynamic-layer

I'm trying to get the noise pollution layer from the following bts.dot.gov ESRI MapServer to render in R:

https://maps.bts.dot.gov/services/rest/services/Noise/CONUS_road_and_aviation_noise/MapServer

I'm using the following code in RStudio (all necessary packages are installed):

```
leaflet() %>% 
  setView(-117.1, 32.9, 10) %>%
  addEsriBasemapLayer(esriBasemapLayers$Oceans, autoLabels = TRUE) %>%
  addEsriDynamicMapLayer( 
    url = paste0("https://maps.bts.dot.gov/services/rest/services/Noise/CONUS_road_and_aviation_noise/MapServer"))
```

However, none of the noise pollution data is being rendered; I only see a blank map.

The following, virtually identical code for an ArcGIS MapServer does work (wildfire data):

```
leaflet() %>% 
  setView(-117.1, 32.9, 10) %>%
  addEsriBasemapLayer(esriBasemapLayers$Oceans, autoLabels = TRUE) %>%
  addEsriDynamicMapLayer( 
    url = paste0("https://maps7.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USDA_USFS_2014_Wildfire_Hazard_Potential/MapServer"))
```

Am I missing something here? The two map services seem very similar, but I have little experience. The BTS map does support dynamic layers, while the Wildfire map does not, but I have tried pulling the map using this option (among others) as well:

```
options = dynamicMapLayerOptions(dynamicLayers = "0")
```

Comment: I just discovered multiple messages in the console like this: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.bts.dot.gov/services/rest/services/Noise/CONUS_road_and_aviation_noise/MapServer/export?bbox=-13042679.44738448%2C3917244.8255587122%2C-12990243.64598085%2C3855025.08453458&size=686%2C814&dpi=96&format=png24&transparent=true&bboxSR=3857&imageSR=3857&f=json due to access control checks."   I'll leave this open just the same should anyone have guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it.  I needed to set useCors to FALSE:

```
leaflet() %>% 
  setView(-117.1, 32.9, 10) %>%
  addEsriBasemapLayer(esriBasemapLayers$Oceans, autoLabels = TRUE) %>%
  addEsriDynamicMapLayer( 
    url = paste0("https://maps.bts.dot.gov/services/rest/services/Noise/CONUS_road_and_aviation_noise/MapServer/"),
    options = dynamicMapLayerOptions(useCors = FALSE))
```